# Normal Distribution of random plot

Tags: plotting, fitting, data, distributions

I have the following data,

```
data = {0.0842, 0.0903, 0.0971, 0.1002, 0.1124, 0.1216, 0.1219, 
  0.1221, 0.1276, 0.1389, 0.1399, 0.1467}

    FindFit[data, 
     a PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x], {a, \[Mu], \[Sigma]},
      x]
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[5.962418792599428` PDF[
    NormalDistribution[17.84715392988593`, 15.248828432325407`], 
    x], {x, 1, 50}], PlotRange -> Full]
```

however the fit is not even close to normal distribution.

Can I somehow get the bell shape fit or bell shape forced fit?

also the real data column bars in the fit.

Comment: The data isn't even close to a normal distribution either - it's more like a straight line y = 0.0807061 + 0.00556958 x. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. Are you looking for `Histogram` ?

Comment: The fit is a multiple of a PDF of a  Normal distribution. It fits the data quit nicely. However, why are you trying to fit this function to data that are certainly are not spread over the definition of the PDF?

Comment: @flinty Danial huber, Thanks, for clearing it up. I thought maybe I am missing something that's why it is not fitting normally.

Comment: Despite having a "good visual fit" to the rising limb of a multiple of a normal distribution, a straight line fit has a much smaller AICc value indicating a straight line has a better relative fit.  Also, if your objective is to predict outside the range of the data, the resulting prediction intervals are going to be huge (resulting in useless predictions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `data` represent? Realisations of a normal distribution? Because you're fitting something very different which is equivalent to:

```
{{1, 0.0842}, {2, 0.0903}, {3, 0.0971}, {4, 0.1002}, {5, 0.1124}, {6, 
  0.1216}, {7, 0.1219}, {8, 0.1221}, {9, 0.1276}, {10, 0.1389}, {11, 
  0.1399}, {12, 0.1467}}
```

Is there ordering to your data? Is there an implicit x-axis?

Regardless, FindFit is not the correct way to fit a distribution to data. It's the wrong tool for the job; distribution estimation is very different from nonlinear regression. You need EstimatedDistribution:

```
EstimatedDistribution[data, NormalDistribution[m, s]]
```

Depending on what your data represent, you may need `WeightedData` as well.

Comment: I must have hit the downvote button while looking at this on my iPhone.  Sorry about that.  If the question get edited, I can then change it to +1.  You point out exactly what needs to be given by the OP to get an appropriate answer to the question.